# Angular 4: How to convert Date to local timezone and display it?

Tags: angular, date, datetime

I want to display date in local time zone. I'm getting date from API which i'm displaying in my HTML code like this way

```
<p>{{item.updatedDate}} </p>
```

Date Format which i'm getting in response is like this **2017-11-30 15:38:02**. But i want to display this in local timezone.

I have tried this and other solutions but i'm not getting how to display date in local timezone format

```
{{item.updatedDate| date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z' }}
```

Comment: That does not look like UTC format to me. UTC formatted would be with either the time zone OR with a Z suffix and T between the date and time.

Comment: I'm not sure about format but i want to display current time in local time zone

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by local time zone format. So your server returns the DateTime formatted as [ISO8601 ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) ? And you want to keep that same display but adjust the time to local time? Or do you want to show the local time AND show it formatted in the culture of the user?

Comment: I want to display the response date in local time zone format

Comment: What is your "local time zone format"? Give us a specific example. So, instead of "2017-11-30 15:38:02", what do you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for parsing the string date and defining a new format for it. Their webpage has all of the data necessary.

You'll have to write your own pipe or a function that will do the conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i don't want to use this...is there any other way or is there any filter in angular 4 to convert it

Comment: The problem is that we don't know in what timezone the original date is in. If you do `new Date('2017-11-30 15:38:02')`, you'll get it in your local timezone as there's no timezone information provided. Possibly you want to display it in a localized format, then you can use `new Date('2017-11-30 15:38:02').toLocaleString()` which will be `"11/30/2017, 3:38:02 PM"` (in my case)? Possibly there's an Angular pipe that would help but first we have to know what exactly you want to do with that date. Please provide a before and after example of what you want to get.